# Need to download csv nightly

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I am struggling to find a way to handle this need. I have a few views exports set up on our site. The Client can go to the view page and download the csv. Works great.

The client is asking to see if the csv's can download nightly without them having to go to the page and click to download. I have not seen something in Drupal that allows me to handle this. I am a front-end dev so not a module creator. I have gone through rules scheduler with no luck.

Can someone try to share some insight to point me in the right direction. Thanks!!!

Comment: my initial recommendation would be either using Rules or defining a hook_cron() job that would execute the view.